# links on self window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, supersized

it is posible to open links on self window ?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(function($){

        $.supersized({

            // Functionality
            slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
            transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition

            // Components                           
            slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                {image : 'slideshow/slides/02.jpg', url : '03.html'},
                                                {image : 'slideshow/slides/03.jpg', url : '02.html'},  
                                                {image : 'slideshow/slides/01.jpg', url : '01.html'}
                                        ]

        });
    });

</script>
```

I tried editing `slide_links: 'blank' <-- self, 0, 1`, but couldn’t make it work.

Comment: Try making a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, you should look at the new_window property. Setting this value to 0 should have the links open in the current window.

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#new_window